# MySQL Query gives error #1054 on newer server version

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My data are spread among two tables:

1. **tbl_archive**: archived data that is no longer updated.
2. **tbl_new**: new table that is continuously being updated.

I need to get the data from both tables while ignoring the duplicates, and if the same row title exist in both, it will take the data from the archived table.

The below query is working fine on my localhost, but resulting in error on my server **#1054 - Unknown column T.ColA**:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT T.ColA, T.ColB, T.ColC
FROM (SELECT title as ColA, url as ColB, source as ColC FROM tbl_archive GROUP BY ColA) AS t
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT name as ColA, path as ColB, origin as ColC FROM tbl_new GROUP BY ColA) AS t2
ON t.ColA = t2.ColA
GROUP BY T.ColA
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT T.ColA, T.ColB, T.ColC
FROM (SELECT name as ColA, path as ColB, origin as ColC FROM tbl_new GROUP BY ColA) AS t
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT title as ColA, url as ColB, source as ColC FROM tbl_archive GROUP BY ColA) AS t2
ON t.ColA = t2.ColA
GROUP BY T.ColA) T GROUP BY `ColA`
```

My table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_archive (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `source` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO tbl_archive (id, title, url, `source`) VALUES
(1, 'A', 'url to A', 'Archive'),
(2, 'B', 'url to B', 'Archive'),
(3, 'C', 'url to C', 'Archive'),
(4, 'D', 'url to D', 'Archive');

CREATE TABLE tbl_new (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `path` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `origin` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO tbl_new (id, `name`, path, origin) VALUES
(1, 'B', 'path to B', 'NEW'),
(2, 'D', 'path to D', 'NEW'),
(3, 'C', 'path to C', 'NEW'),
(4, 'E', 'path to E', 'NEW');
```

[The result on my localhost is correct as per this snapshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev5PG.png)

**My localhost info:**

- Server: localhost via TCP/IP
- Server type: MySQL
- Server version: 5.7.11 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- Protocol version: 10
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

**My external server:**

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
- Server version: 10.4.12-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
- Protocol version: 10
- Server charset: cp1252 West European (latin1)

I appreciate if anyone can help me get this to work.

Comment: not your immediate problem but Group by without aggregate functions is unlikely to be useful. BTW mariadb is not mysql and is not a newer DB server version. And I cannot reproduce error in mariadb 10.4.6

Comment: I thought about writing the servers type and versions of my localhost and external server because they are not the same. I'm accessing both servers through phpMyAdmin and the code is only working on my localhost.

Comment: This is an effect of `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL Server Mode. And formally the query is wrong (language extension allows you execite this wrong query on your localhost server, but the output is non-deterministic, and may be visually correct but logically wrong).

Comment: @Akina can you please guide me how should the query be?

Comment: I don't understand the logic which you try to realize. So I cannot.

Comment: And then how did you determine that my query is wrong? I have already explained what I am trying to achieve.